# Slim framework 404 error

Tags: php, routes, slim

I try to use Slim framework but I have a problem with the route system. I try to go to "/contact" but I have a 404 error on my web browser. However, when I try to access "/index.php/contact", the server display the good response. Here is my code for the routes:

```
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) use ($app) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello me");

    return $response; 
});

$app->get('/contact', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Contact page");

    return $response;
});
```

And here is my .htaccess in public directory (it is the same in the "first application" tutorial in the official Slim framework website):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try with this htaccess : `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Slim returns "Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET" :(

Comment: If Slim returns "Method not allowed.." then route is working correctly. You need to use GET method, and not, for example POST. Just open browser and use URL `http://yourowndomain.com/contact`

Comment: You don't fix my problem because I want to know why I have this error message when I do "/ contact" and why I must write "/index.php/contact" to make it work when I only want "/contact".

Comment: How rude! Please post your .htaccess file or virtual host config settings. But it seems to me you've messed up by having `use ($app)` at the root route,